# How to Check Custom template for Posts by default in WP Post Template Plugin

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am using WP Post Template for Post Template

> I have two template

- Default Template (Selected By Default)
- Property

> and I want

- Default Template
- Property (Select By Default)

Comment: what you have tried? can you post both templates here with code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to change code into page.php file. Find below code on same file.

```
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
        get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );

            // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, load up the comment template.
            if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
                comments_template();
            endif;

        endwhile; // End of the loop.
```

Please change `get_template_part( 'template-parts/page/content', 'page' );` this line with

```
get_template_part( 'inc/template', 'property' );
```

For that you need to set your template file name is template-property.php

Comment: This post is useful?

Comment: Actually, I want code to set it default as property Template not like this